# Can Packer connect to a VM in vSphere via SSH?

Tags: ssh, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, packer

I'm just getting started with configuring a VM on VMware vSphere and I'm using HashiCorp Packer to create the VM template. I'm very pleased with how most things are working out for me, but I have a couple of questions regarding how Packer connects to the virtual machine, and I'm hoping that someone over here can help me.

I am using the `vsphere-iso` builder from [the VMWare vSphere plugin](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/vsphere/vsphere-iso).

1. Is the `ssh_password` field required? Things seems to fail when I don't set it, but it says nowhere that it is required (as it says for `ssh_username`, for example).
2. I read [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/vsphere/vsphere-iso#ssh_clear_authorized_keys) about the `ssh_clear_authorized_keys` that *"If true, Packer will attempt to remove its temporary key from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`"*. What temporary key? Is that used for authentication during provisioning? What on earth is `ssh_password` for then?